# Why are unrelated one-shots by Masami Tsuda included in compilations of Kare Kano?

Tags: manga-production, kare-kano

While reading *Kare Kano*, I noticed that the extras included in [the tankobon compilations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Kare_Kano_chapters) seem to have absolutely no relation to the story of the main manga. (I have just finished the fourth volume of *Kare Kano*, so I've read both "The Tiger and the Chameleon: A Promise for One Week" and "Meet Me Again Tomorrow in the Forest". The former involves students in high school and has a romance theme, but it does not seem to belong to the same setting as *Kare Kano*. The latter is a story of a half-alien, half-human girl's experiences with racism on another planet.)

This observation was backed-up by some research that I did: the two extras that I have read so far appear to be works written by [Masumi Tsuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masami_Tsuda) in 1994 and 1993 respectively, *prior* to her publication of *Kare Kano*.

Why were pre-existing unrelated works included as extras? In the past, had other manga compilations done the same thing? I could imagine this as a means to "promote" the author or provide readers with bonus content at low cost, but in other manga that I've read, such as *Fullmetal Alchemist*, extra one-shots were clearly related to the main content.

Comment: I haven't seen this very often, but I have seen a couple other manga series that packaged one-shots outside the main continuity. For example, the first volume of _Hellsing_ included a one-shot by Kouta Hirano about two members of the Isacariot organization that was sort of a prototype for the main _Hellsing_ series. I think they do this in some cases because the one-shot is of interest to fans of the series, but hard to track down because it was published in a magazine and never got a tankoubon release. I have no proof, though.

Comment: Update: I've been reading _Scum's Wish_, and I've noticed that some extras featuring cats (also mentioned [here](https://daiyamanga.com/2015/10/08/manga-review-scums-wish/)) that have absolutely no obvious relation to the main plot. I don't know whether these are pre-existing works or not though.